# Physically move mssql instance with service broker to another server

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

What we are doing is simply shutting down sql server and physically moving mssql folder to another server. After that operation service broker not working correctly. What to do to make service broker work on a new server? What's the correct way to move whole server to a new machine?

We have merge replication which we dont want to reinitiallize. So backup/restore and attach/deattach is not a good option. Any solutions for reanimation of service broker on a new machine? Recreate certificates/create new SB guid (NEW BROKER)?

Comment: you install SQL Server using the normal setup. Than you make a backup of your database on the old server, copy it to the new server, and restore it on the new server. Just like any other application

Comment: we have merge replication running, so we can't do backup/restore. I think we may be need to make deattach or smth, or just recreate certificates for service broker and swap old ones with new

Comment: you can do detach / attach also that is no problem. What is important is that you install SQL Server using the normal setup not by copying its folder

Comment: yes, i didnt meant that we will not install SQL Server, i meant that we going to move database files. Will detach/attach move logins and everything? Will service broker work with old certificates created on another instance?

Comment: backup/restore will try to move logins and everything I am not sure if detach/attach also does.

Comment: backup/restore will force reinitiallize subscribtion on merge replication, which is pain. Also, i think attach/deattach wont work with merge replication too.

Comment: Both backup/restore and attach/detach transfer *data pages*. The difference is that attach/detach also copies empty data pages. If that data contains database security objects they'll be transferred as well

Comment: @SergeyLobanov I suggest you read up on how backup/restore and replication works and check guides on SQL Server migrations. This is *not* something that can be answered in a *developer* Q&A site. This is 1000% DBA territory. Data, security principals, certificates and replication settings can be migrated but it's *not* a copy/paste operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, we moved folder with database files to fresh new instance of sql server on another machine. After few tests we get the expected error `An error occurred while receiving data: '10054(An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)'.` and in SQLProfiler it shows as `Connection handshake failed. Error 15581 occurred while initializing the private key corresponding to the certificate. The SQL Server errorlog and the Windows event log may contain entries related to this error. State 88.`.
So, i've tried to regenerate master keys on both main database and master database. And it worked. Service broker running good on both directions.

```
USE <dbName>;
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';

ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';

CLOSE MASTER KEY;

USE master;

OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';

ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';

CLOSE MASTER KEY;
```